# android Gridlayout how to align all images into 3 X 2 grid?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

How to create a grid layout that aligns the images into 3 rows and 2 coulmns.
I tried with a linearlayout but it doesn't work as for image I have to specify the height and width.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/mycolor"
            tools:src="@drawable/image" />

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/mycolor"
            tools:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/mycolor"
            tools:src="@drawable/image" />

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/mycolor"
            tools:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/mycolor"
            tools:src="@drawable/image" />

 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/mycolor"
            tools:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works but not for all screen sizes, can anyone suggest how to build a grid layout of 3 X 2 for images?

Answer (score 0):

For an easy implementation, you can use a RecyclerView that displays your data in fixed columns as a grid.

I would suggest reading the [CodeLabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-grid-layout) for a quick pattern.